# SSIS 2008-Error "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data"

Tags: ssis

I am trying to transfer data from a DB2(source) table to SQL(destination) table.
While executing the task I am getting below errors:

```
Error# 1
[OLE DB Source [1525]] Error: There was an error with output column "ABC" (1545) on output "OLE DB Source Output" (1535). The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Error# 2
[OLE DB Source [1525]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "output column "ABC" (1545)" failed because error code 0xC0209072 occurred, and the error row disposition on "output column "ABC" (1545)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Error# 3
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The PrimeOutput method on component "OLE DB Source" (1525) returned error code 0xC0209029. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

Comment: What is the data type of your source column (ABC), and what conversions (implicit or otherwise) are you doing in your package?  An explicit conversion could be something like a Data Conversion or a Derived Column Transformation, whereas an implicit conversion would be if you were trying to insert the data into a destination column with a different data type (e.g., in DB2 you have a character field that you're trying to insert into a SQL integer field). Click the 'edit' button under your question and modify it to include the data types of source and destination, and any transformations between.

Comment: The error says that the problem is in the OLEDB source component.  I would try doing a conversion on column ABC to varchar, then convert it to the correct type in the data flow

Comment: Source (db2) column is varchar and destination(SQL) is also varchar. I am not using any data convertion or derived column. Ssis data DT str...I am new to Ssis, pls help